# Invalid XML for View Architecture when adding messages into views

Tags: xml, view, odoo, openerp-7

I want to add messages into my module,
I inherited mail.thread class:

```
inherit= ['mail.thread','ir.needaction_mixin']
```

and made the required depedency:

```
'depends': ['base','mail']
```

and everything was working fine, but when I add these four lines code after  to add the messages into my module:

```
<record id="travel_info_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">travel.info.view</field>
             <field name="type">form</field>
             <field name="model">travel.info</field>
             <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="travel.info" version="7.0">

                   <sheet>

                       ----

                   </sheet>

                    <div class="oe_chatter">
                          <field name="message_follower_ids" widget="mail_followers" groups="base.group_user"/>
                          <field name="message_ids" widget="mail_thread"/>
                    </div>

             </form>


        </field>
        </record>
```

**an error shows up:**
('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')

What is the reason??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the error, it was typo error with inheritance

I wrote:

inherit= ['mail.thread','ir.needaction_mixin']

the right one is:

_inherit = 'mail.thread'

Comment: you can approve your answer so others can get help from it.